# my SQL query for updating using vars in query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <h2>Event</h2>
 <br/>
 Update : <select name="updateevents"><option value="">New...</option>
 <?php $host="127.0.0.1"; 
 $user="belgiumca_db"; 
 $pw=""; 
 $db="belgiumca_db";

 $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
 mysql_select_db($db);

  $sql ="SELECT*FROM event";

 $result= mysql_query($sql);
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<option value='".$data['ID']."'>".base64_decode($data['eventitle'])."</option>";
 }
mysql_query($sql); 

 mysql_close($verbinding);
 ?>
 </select>
 &nbsp;<input name="load" type="submit" value="load">
 <br/>
 <?php
$update="false";
  if(isset($_POST['load']) && $_POST['updateevents'] !="")
   {
$update="true";
```

// setting $idevent --> the content of update events (ID)

```
       $idevent=$_POST['updateevents'];
$host="127.0.0.1"; 
    $user="belgiumca_db"; 
    $pw=""; 
    $db="belgiumca_db";

    $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
    mysql_select_db($db);
    echo $idevent;
    $sql ="SELECT * 
    FROM  `event` 
    WHERE  `ID` ='".$idevent."'";
    $result= mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
  echo "<br/>Selected: ".$data['ID']." ".base64_decode($data['eventitle'])."<br/>";
  $eventtitle=base64_decode($data['eventitle']);
    }

 }
 ?>
 <br/>
 titel event: <input name="titleevent"   type="text" value="<?php echo $eventtitle; ?     >"   placeholder="Titel v/h event">
 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
 Text Event :<br/> <div id="txt"><textarea name="txtevent"   cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>   </div>
 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
 datum1 event: <input name="date1" id="datepicker"   type="text" placeholder="begindatum in    dag/maand/jaar"><br/><br/>datum2event : <input name="date2" id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="begindatum in dag/maand/jaar">
 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
 photolink:
 <br/>
 <input   name="plink" type="text" placeholder="Photo link (bcc) voorlopig fb">
 <br/>
 videolink:
 <br/>
 <input   name="vlink" type="text" placeholder="Youtube link - video">
 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
 miniimagelink1:
<br/>
<input   name="miniimage1" type="text" placeholder="mini-image via facebook link hier">
<br/>
image preview:
<br/>
<img height="180" width="240" src="<?php echo $prevminiimg1;?>">
 <br/>
 miniimagelink2:
 <br/>
 <input   name="miniimage2" type="text" placeholder="mini-image via facebook link hier">
 <br/>
 image preview:
 <br/>
 <img height="180" width="240" src="<?php echo $prevminiimg2;?>">
 <br/>
  miniimagelink3:
  <br/>
   <input   name="miniimage3" type="text" placeholder="mini-image via facebook link hier">
   <br/>
   image preview:
   <br/>
   <img height="180" width="240" src="<?php echo $prevminiimg3;?>">
   <br/>
   miniimagelink4:
   <br/>
   <input   name="miniimage4" type="text" placeholder="mini-image via facebook link hier" >
   <br/>
   image preview:
   <br/>
   <img height="180" width="240" src="<?php echo $prevminiimg4;?>">
   <br/>
   <br/>
   Tags: <input name="tags" type="text" size="50">
   <br/>
   <input name="SAVE" type="submit" value="SAVE">
   </form>
   <?php 
   echo "id : ".$_POST['updateevents'];
   if(isset($_POST['SAVE']))
   {
    $id=$_POST['updateevents'];
if($_POST['date1'] != "" && $_POST['date2']!="")
{
     $eventdate=$_POST['date1']." - ".$_POST['date2'];  
}
else
{
    $eventdate=$_POST['date1'];
}
    $host="127.0.0.1"; 
    $user="belgiumca_db"; 
    $pw=""; 
    $db="belgiumca_db"; 

     $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
     mysql_select_db($db);
```

// update query

```
      $sql = "UPDATE `event`
      SET    `eventitle`='".base64_encode($_POST['titleevent'])."',`eventtxt`='".base64_encode($_POST['txtevent'])."',`eventdate`='".base64_encode($eventdate)."',`miniimage1`='".base64_encode($_POST['miniimage1'])."',`miniimage2`='".base64_encode($_POST['miniimage2'])."',`miniimage3`='".base64_encode($_POST['miniimage3'])."',`miniimage4`='".base64_encode($_POST['miniimage4'])."',`IP`='".$ipaddress."',`date`='".date('d-m-Y--H:i:s')."',`videolink`='".base64_encode($_POST['vlink'])."',`photolink`='".base64_encode($_POST['plink'])."',`tags`='".base64_encode($_POST['tags'])."' WHERE `ID`='".$id."'";
    echo $sql;
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($verbinding);
   ?>`
```

// the full code is mentioned above hope any of you guys can solve it with this  the problem is that my $id or $ideevent is not able to be use in my UPDATE query in the SQL Query

Comment: try adding echoing mysql_error() after mysql_query() and see what happens

Comment: mysql_error() will tell u whats happening in the query

Comment: what is the error ?? and before running echo the $sql and see what is the output

Comment: mysql_error() isn't giving any output i use echo and print none of this worked as expected any other ideas ?

Comment: `echo $sql` and post it here. And what is the data type of your `date` column in the table?

Comment: @user3432892 post the result of echo $sql

Comment: `eventitle`='U2t5bGltaXQgVHJhY2tkYXkgMg==',`eventtxt`='',`eventdate`='',`miniimage1`='',`miniimage2`='',`miniimage3`='',`miniimage4`='',`IP`='note:myipwashere',`date`='18-03-2014--12:48:40',`videolink`='',`photolink`='',`tags`='' WHERE `ID` =''

Comment: *The event title is entered as only one and it's not getting his id ...

Comment: @user3432892 not that, try my answer and put the error.

Comment: @user3432892 in your query Value of ID id missing

Comment: I quess the problem is getting the ID i put it in a variable somewhere so it catches it from another script in the page could this be the problem ?

Comment: @user3432892: So you got where the error is !

Comment: @echo_Me He tried I guess but no results. The problem is the `$id` I think. Never defined ?

Comment: @echo_Me: Yes. That is what as seen from the echoed sql statement. It should alert the OP that it is the error.

Comment: @Debflav yes its the id , i have said it in my answer and the comments under my answer

Comment: @user3432892: And I also fear that your `date` input format is wrong.

Comment: the date is for analytics only no visitor will ever see it i created it just for safety (knowing when it's posted on which ip )

Comment: Can anyone help me with the newly updated code above ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
  mysql_query($sql);
```

use

```
  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //to see whats wrong.
```

EDIT:

im guessing that your variable `$id` is not defined , thats why the update couldnt find this id to make update.

Comment: I get nothing not even a single character when using that command

Comment: @user3432892 it means nothing is wrong just the $id is not defined it may be 0 . try echo $id before that statment and see if there is value

Comment: at the top of the page i get the id and close the "?>" again so normally it wouldn't be not defined...

Comment: causing of some reason the variable doesn't seem to get changed to it

Comment: if you have id and no error in your sql , then you have some condition which doesnt lead to this code of updating , better show your full code.

Comment: from all this code you posted you didnt mention where $id is defined .

Comment: echo "id : ".$_POST['updateevents'];
if(isset($_POST['SAVE']))
{// if i do it this way it works(echo) 
if(isset($_POST['SAVE'])){echo "id : ".$_POST['updateevents'];
// and like this it won't echo the $_POST value any idea how to fix this issue  ?

Comment: the id is set here $id=base64_decode['ID']; $sql ="SELECT * 
    FROM  `event` 
    WHERE  `ID` ='".$id."'";

Comment: im tired saying everytime show your code where you are defining $id , and this $id i dont think its true.

Comment: I updated the code above i also added the html + the needed php

Comment: i dont know why you suing <form> in all your page including php code!! why dont you use it only for the html form which you will submit only? you will not submit the queries ans so on . and to be sure that your id is wrong try replace this in your query update with an number `WHERE ID='12'` replace 12 with some valid number from table. and dude else please debugg it yourself im not rewriting your code.

Comment: I solved the problem by writing the variabel to a table in a column and then getting it back